# How to manipulate IRIS data set?

Tags: r

I need to include more species to the iris data set, the following plot only presents three species. How Can I make the code more flexible to include more than three species?

[image]

Comment: The built in `iris` dataset only has three species. Are you trying to use different data? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please don't post code or data as images since we can't copy/paste that into R for testing

Comment: Try pairs: `pairs(iris[-5], col = iris[[5]])`

Answer (score 0):

You are plotting the points on a single graph. You do not need a loop:

```
clrs <- rainbow(length(levels(iris$Species)))
plot(Petal.Width~Petal.Length, iris, main="My Graph", xlab="Petal Length", ylab="Petal Width", col=clrs[as.numeric(iris$Species)])
legend("topleft", legend=levels(iris$Species), pch=1, col=clrs)
```

[image: Plot]